# android replace status bar and prevent access to existing status bar

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, statusbar

I've read several posts on here, and none of them are exactly what I am looking for.  They got me a long way, but I have one issue that I still need to resolve.

I am using Xamarin for Android and I am currently targeting API level 14 and above.

I have the following code (C# and Xamarin)

```
IWindowManager windowManager;
WindowManagerLayoutParams parm = null;

View statusBarView = new View(this);

windowManager = GetSystemService(Context.WindowService).JavaCast<IWindowManager>();

statusBarView.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Green);

parm = new WindowManagerLayoutParams(WindowManagerLayoutParams.FillParent, 400,
                                     WindowManagerTypes.SystemOverlay, 
                                     WindowManagerFlags.LayoutNoLimits,
                                     Format.Transparent);

parm.Gravity = GravityFlags.Top;

windowManager.AddView(statusBarView, parm);
```

Note: the 400 is just a number I threw in there for testing, I will actually get the actual height of the status bar.

This displays just fine, but the user can still get to the Notification Bar.   There are several applications out there that do what I'm looking to do, I just need help with the last piece of the puzzle.

That piece is how to prevent touch events from getting to the current status bar.

All help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You want to hide the status bar? 
If yes, https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html

Comment: That still allows the user to access the default one.  I need to replace the existing one.

Comment: I don't think you can remove him without root (nova requires root to do that if I remember right).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable statusbar, use this

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)

{
customViewGroup view = new customViewGroup(this);

            WindowManagerLayoutParams localLayoutParams = new WindowManagerLayoutParams();
            localLayoutParams.Type = WindowManagerTypes.SystemError;
            localLayoutParams.Gravity = GravityFlags.Top;
            localLayoutParams.Flags = WindowManagerFlags.NotFocusable |
            WindowManagerFlags.NotTouchModal | WindowManagerFlags.LayoutInScreen;
            localLayoutParams.Width = WindowManagerLayoutParams.MatchParent;
            localLayoutParams.Height = (int)(50 * Resources.DisplayMetrics.ScaledDensity);
            localLayoutParams.Format = Format.Transparent;

            manager.AddView(view, localLayoutParams);

}


public class customViewGroup : ViewGroup
        {
            public customViewGroup(Context context) : base(context)
            {
            }
            public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
            {
                return true;
            }
            protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
            {
                // throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
```

For enable again use

```
manager.RemoveView(view);
```